# SQL- calculating daily stock levels for month as aggregate of availability

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a table containing following records of stocks from different depots in region. this contains:

1. itemName
2. startDate
3. endDate
4. quantity

The fields are

1. key(pk)
2. itemName- numeric code
3. startDate- date
4. endDate- date
5. amt- number

Sample data with 3 item types

```
1     101     Jan 1,  2013    Jan 14, 2013    15  
2     101     Jan 12, 2013    Jan 15, 2013    3  
3     102     Jan 4,  2013    Jan 26, 2013    7  
4     102     Jan 6,  2013    Jan 12, 2013    19              
5     103     Jan 15, 2013    Jan 16, 2013    3  
6     103     Jan 12, 2013    Jan 21, 2013    19
```

How do I write a query that will get the number of items of each time every day in this period? Essentially I need to have a query that will add up applicable items between startDate and endDate. Thanks

I would want a final query result to look like that would add overlaps for each item

```
Jan 1   101  15  
Jan 1   102  0  
Jan 12  101  18  
Jan 15  101  3   
Jan 16  101  3
```

while I know i can do for a given date

```
SELECT item, sum(amt) 
FROM [table] 
WHERE (date>=startdate) AND (date<=enddate) 
GROUP BY item
```

How do I enable it iterate for the whole month(Jan 1st to 31st) to produce such a report?

Comment: Put the desired schema !!

Comment: What have you tried ? Also, can you post your table structure ? What did you try that you have not succeeded doing.

Comment: thanks- have added the schema and what i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

Create a table named [DayNumbers] and fill it with the numbers from 1 through 31:

```
DayNumber
---------
        1
        2
        3
...
       30
       31
```

Now create a saved query in Access named [MonthDates] to create a row for each day in a specified month:

```sql
PARAMETERS SelectedYear Long, SelectedMonth Long;
SELECT DateSerial([SelectedYear], [SelectedMonth], DayNumber) AS StatusDate
FROM DayNumbers
WHERE Month(DateSerial([SelectedYear], [SelectedMonth], DayNumber)) = [SelectedMonth];
```

Note that the WHERE clause restricts the number of days to the actual number of days in the month (e.g., 30 for April).

Create another saved query in Access named [StockStatusRows] to create a row for each day and each item

```sql
SELECT StatusDate, itemName
FROM 
    MonthDates, 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT itemName FROM StockData
    )  AS Items;
```

For test data in [StockStatus] that looks like

```
key  itemName  startDate   endDate     amt
---  --------  ----------  ----------  ---
  1  101       2013-01-01  2013-01-14   15
  2  101       2013-01-12  2013-01-15    3
  3  102       2013-01-04  2013-01-26    7
  4  102       2013-01-06  2013-01-12   19
  5  103       2013-01-15  2013-01-16    3
  6  103       2013-01-12  2013-01-21   19
  7  101       2013-01-30  2013-02-03    6
  8  102       2013-02-05  2013-02-23    9
  9  103       2013-02-07  2013-03-02   11
```

the [StockStatusRows] query will return

```
StatusDate  itemName
----------  --------
2013-01-01  101     
2013-01-02  101     
2013-01-03  101     
..
2013-01-30  101     
2013-01-31  101     
2013-01-01  102     
2013-01-02  102     
2013-01-03  102     
...
2013-01-30  102     
2013-01-31  102     
2013-01-01  103     
2013-01-02  103     
2013-01-03  103     
...
2013-01-30  103     
2013-01-31  103
```

Now we can pull together the actual stock values like so:

```sql
SELECT ssr.StatusDate, ssr.itemName, Nz(sums.total, 0) AS TotalOnHand
FROM 
    StockStatusRows AS ssr 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (   
        SELECT StatusDate, itemName, Sum(amt) AS total
        FROM
            (
                SELECT md.StatusDate, sd.itemName, sd.amt
                FROM 
                    StockData sd 
                    INNER JOIN 
                    MonthDates md 
                        ON md.StatusDate>=sd.startDate 
                            And md.StatusDate<=sd.endDate
            )
        GROUP BY StatusDate, itemName
    )  AS sums 
        ON (sums.itemName=ssr.itemName) 
            AND (sums.StatusDate=ssr.StatusDate)
ORDER BY ssr.StatusDate, ssr.itemName;
```

returning

```
StatusDate  itemName  TotalOnHand
----------  --------  -----------
2013-01-01  101       15         
2013-01-01  102       0          
2013-01-01  103       0          
2013-01-02  101       15         
2013-01-02  102       0          
2013-01-02  103       0          
2013-01-03  101       15         
2013-01-03  102       0          
2013-01-03  103       0          
2013-01-04  101       15         
2013-01-04  102       7          
2013-01-04  103       0          
2013-01-05  101       15         
2013-01-05  102       7          
2013-01-05  103       0          
2013-01-06  101       15         
2013-01-06  102       26         
2013-01-06  103       0          
...
2013-01-12  101       18         
2013-01-12  102       26         
2013-01-12  103       19         
2013-01-13  101       18         
2013-01-13  102       7          
2013-01-13  103       19         
2013-01-14  101       18         
2013-01-14  102       7          
2013-01-14  103       19         
2013-01-15  101       3          
2013-01-15  102       7          
2013-01-15  103       22         
2013-01-16  101       0          
2013-01-16  102       7          
2013-01-16  103       22         
2013-01-17  101       0          
2013-01-17  102       7          
2013-01-17  103       19         
...
2013-01-22  101       0          
2013-01-22  102       7          
2013-01-22  103       0          
...
2013-01-31  101       6          
2013-01-31  102       0          
2013-01-31  103       0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select itemName from <Table-Name> where startDate>=(start-date) startDate<=(end-date) and endDate>=(start-date) and endDate<=(end-date) group by itemName.
```

This would calculate the sum of quantities of each product between (start-date) and (end-date).

If you want just total of all items irrespective of their type,

```
select sum(quantity) from <Table-Name> where startDate>=(start-date) startDate<=(end-date) and endDate>=(start-date) and endDate<=(end-date)
```

Hope this helps